# Read Uncommitted Isolation Level Impact On Insert/Update Transactions

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, deadlock, database-deadlocks

my application is having deadlock issue where there is a possibility of conflict from three different sides:

1) MySQL database event - that executed every minutes and run couple of update commands in transactions.
2) Background task = that run every seconds and run couple of insert/update commands in transaction.(doctrine)
3) Main FrontEnd API call - based on incoming request, run insert/update commands. Because of high traffic, request density, this is also of high density.(doctrine)

So, what so far I understood by read from internet is that, lowest isolation level 'read uncommitted' will help to perform dirty perform, thus helping minimize deadlocks. But, here in my case, all conflicting operations are **UPDATE/INSERT** .

Will that isolation level will help here in this case at all?? 

-- EDIT --

Hello, actually I read that and one of the points there is to use a lower isolation level. However, **my main question was about the impact of 'read uncommitted' isolation level to update operation**, not asking for a solution on deadlock.

Comment: I am not sure whether changing the isolation level is a silver bullet to avoid deadlocks. This even might make the problem worse is some cases (unless you change it to `serializable`, but this affects the performance). The deadlock is a situation when two actions (sessions) wait each other to get access to locked resources, not the problem of improper isolation level. If you need further assistance you need to determine the cause of the deadlock, and show transactions (SQL code) involved in the deadlock, this link can be helpful: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html .

Comment: Hello, actually I read that and one of the points there is to use a lower isolation level. However, my main question was about the impact of 'read uncommitted' isolation level to update operation, not asking for a solution on deadlock. Thanks anyway...

Comment: `impact of isolation levels to update operation in MySql` - hmmm, it's a very wide topic :). For now, please study very carefully these two links: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html  and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html , I will try to comment this tommorow or day after tommorow when I'll have some spare time.

Comment: Great, thanks for the links. Also, looking forward to your thoughts on this soon.