# Impact of transaction isolation in write operations in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, transactions

I have a mysql proc which does one read and one update (in 2 different tables). To make sure read is fast, I changed the isolation level to Read Uncommitted. Dirty read is ok and the data consistency does not really matter. But it looks in Read Uncommitted Isolation level, updates are very slow - in fact it impacts other writes in my table.

My code looks like this

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

SELECT ParentId INTO @ParentId FROM TableA where Id = var_ID;



UPDATE TableB SET Counter = Counter + 1 where Id = @ParentId;

SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```

I was in assumption that The Isolation level impact only read operations, not write. After I included the Set Session.... statement the performance of my database went down drastically. All writes on TableB takes 1-2 seconds whereas it was <100ms before (Table has 5M-8M records).

Can anyone help with some pointers to it?

I found similar question here, but could not get an answer

[Read Uncommitted Isolation Level Impact On Insert/Update Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661779/read-uncommitted-isolation-level-impact-on-insert-update-transactions)

Comment: Not directly related, but there's a red flag, here: `SELECT INTO` with user-defined variables (prefixed with `@`) [leads to unexpected behavior](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35207/11651) if the `WHERE` clause matches 0 rows. You expect the variable to be `NULL` but it won't necessarily be.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot: Thanks, I have set it to Null earlier in the script (Not copied, though). Noticed when using variables prefixed with @ in where clause, index is not being used. I think it is to do with datatype of column and variable has to be same. I chaged to variable of type Declare var_ParentId CHAR(36) and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

SELECT ParentId INTO @ParentId FROM TableA where Id = var_ID;



UPDATE TableB SET Counter = Counter + 2 where Id = @ParentId;

SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```